# Data model and traversal approach for bus routing in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, routes, graph-databases

I'm trying to create an application to find the best paths to use when traveling by bus within my local city. I have found some useful answers on here so far, but I'm currently struggeling with my approach in general and I'd like to get some feedback.

**Current data model**

There are **stations** and **stages** modeled as nodes and two relationships between stations and stops. Each stage node has a **start** and an **end** time as a string in "HH:mm" format and belongs to some higher-level structure which I call **routes**, that are connected to these stage nodes to describe a trajectory along stations with time details. Each **:FROM** relationship has a property **duration** to model the travel time for reduce statements.

So the following query would return something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7nb4.png). The stage nodes show the **start** property in the picture.

```
match (from:Station {name: "Glosberg"})
match (to:Station {name: "Knellendorf"})
match paths=((from)-[:FROM|:TO*..10]->(to))
return paths;
```

**Problems so far:**

1. **ShortestPath**/**AllShortestPaths** is not a valid option as smallest number of hops does not mean best path. What I want is a reduction of travel duration, which I can achive with a **Reduce** statement, which I have already done. Since I have to check out all paths I'm using the general pattern matcher with a limit (as seen above). The limit I use in my queries is actually the length of the shortest paths between **from** and **to** plus 10% or so to also include paths that might consist of more hops but take less time. This is not necessarily accurate but seems like a fair trade-off.
2. Using dijkstra gives me all paths from **A** to **B**. Since stage nodes have a form of time data on them, most of the paths do not make sense, because they are either combined in reversed order (2pm -> 1pm) or produce long waiting times (2pm -> 4pm), which are not necessary. Therefore I have to filter out bad paths, either in cypher or at some api level. However, with the current data model there simply are too many paths to check for validity. With some sample data, which would also run in production, I have a route that visits 24 stations 2 times a day, resulting in 2^23 paths to take. I'm pretty sure that my data model is the problem, but I can't see any ways to solve this; any ideas?

**Questions:**

1. More of a side problem: How would you solve ordering paths with stages that go past 0am? As "23:59" is bigger than "00:01" but not chronologically.
2. What would you change about the data model?
3. Would you suggest any trade-offs in how the path finding works to reduce the complexity (eg. simply using shortestpath)?
4. Would you suggest seperating the actual route data (timetable, who stops where and when) from the infrastructure data (stations and which stations are close to which)? That way I'd have to and use neo4j to find a path/set of stations to travel along and then try to find a suiting set of elements from a timetable, similiar to [wanderu's approach](http://de.slideshare.net/neo4j/neo4j-webinarfinal).

I've read that the traversal api is a better way to describe how the graph should be accessed instead of using cypher, which only describes what to look for, but I'd like to receive feedback on my thoughs until now before I dive into that.